# HTML - Submit button does not work

Tags: javascript, html, search, button

Please, this code is a search bar that redirects the user to a page according to the word inserted.

But the **submit button does not work** ... only works if the user presses the "Enter" key.

Can anyone help?

```
<datalist id="mylist">
    <option value="red">
    <option value="blue">
    <option value="black">
    <option value="white">
  </datalist>


<!-- Input Colors -->
<input type="hidden" id="red"  name="red" value="RED" required>
<input type="hidden" id="blue"  name="blue" value="BLUE" required>
<input type="hidden" id="black"  name="black" value="BLACK" required>
<input type="hidden" id="white"  name="white" value="WHITE" required>


<!-- Search Bar -->
<form>
  <input type="search" list="mylist" id="search" placeholder="What Color?" name="search_box" required autocomplete="off"
   onsearch="check(this)">
  <input type="submit">
</form>



<script>
function check(input) 

{
<!-- Validation Color 1 -->
if (input.value.toUpperCase() != document.getElementById('red').value)
{
<!-- Validation Color 2 -->
if (input.value.toUpperCase() != document.getElementById('blue').value)  
{
<!-- Validation Color 3 -->
if (input.value.toUpperCase() != document.getElementById('black').value) 
{ 
<!-- Validation Color 4 -->
if (input.value.toUpperCase() != document.getElementById('white').value) 
{


<!-- Action web site color WHITE -->
} 
else 
{ 
parent.location.href = 'http://www.websitecolor.com/white'
}


<!-- Action web site color BLACK -->
} 
else 
{ 
parent.location.href = 'http://www.websitecolor.com/black'
}


<!-- Action web site color BLUE -->
} 
else 
{ 
parent.location.href = 'http://www.websitecolor.com/blue'
}


<!-- Action web site color RED -->
} 
else 
{ 
parent.location.href = 'http://www.websitecolor.com/red'
}

}
</script>
```

Comment: 1. not sure how broad support for `onsearch` event handler is. 2. You can not have HTML comments inside your JavaScript code, that’s just going to cause syntax errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [W3C Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onsearch.asp):

> The onsearch event occurs when a user presses the "ENTER" key or clicks the "x" button in an `<input>` element with type="search".

A submit button in the same form as a search field does not trigger the search fields `onsearch` event. Instead it submits the whole form. Since there is no `action` set, it will submit to the same page you are on, effectively reloading it (with the data from the form sent using `GET`).

I take it that you want to call the function `check` instead, with a reference to the search field as a parameter. Then you might as well use an input of type button instead of submit, and you should add an `onclick` event. It would look something like this:

```
<form>
  <input type="search" list="mylist" id="search" placeholder="What Color?" name="search_box" required autocomplete="off"
   onsearch="check(this)">
  <input type="button" onclick="check(document.getElementById('search'))">
</form>
```